# How does app_offline.htm handles current active sessions in IIS/asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know that if I add the page **app___offline.htm** to the websites root it will act as the site is down and will show the content of app___offline.htm to new users visiting the site.

But what happends to the existing active sessions on the site, are those also redirected to the app___offline.htm or can they finnish their work and exit nicely?

I plan to update a server where a webbooking application is running and want that 40 minutes before I start the update it will close for new users but let the users already started a booking to have a chance to finnish it.

So I wonder if using the  app___offline.htm could be a easy/fast solution to that, If not I'll code that behaviour myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shuts the App Domain down.  So existing sessions are lost.